# Solving Sudoku in VBA. How do I make my code more efficient?

Tags: vba, sudoku

I have been trying to write VBA code that will solve Sudoku and have found that my code is very bloated. This is what I have so far (and it only solves the left most column for now. In order to write the rest of the code this way, I would need to add 9 x 27 lookup variables...)

```
Dim i, j As Integer
Dim emptyrow, emptycol As Collection
Dim emptycellcount As Integer
Dim range1, lookup1, lookup2, lookup3, lookup4, lookup5, lookup6, lookup7,    lookup8, lookup9 As Range

Set emptyrow = New Collection
Set emptycol = New Collection

''''obtain coordinates of missing cells'''

With Range("A1")
    For i = 1 To 9
        For j = 1 To 9
            If .Offset(i, j).Value = "" Then
                emptyrow.Add i
                emptycol.Add j
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
End With

emptycellcount = emptyrow.Count

Set range1 = Range("A1").Offset(1, 1).Resize(9, 1)
Set lookup1 = range1.Find(1, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
Set lookup2 = range1.Find(2, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
Set lookup3 = range1.Find(3, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
Set lookup4 = range1.Find(4, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
Set lookup5 = range1.Find(5, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
Set lookup6 = range1.Find(6, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
Set lookup7 = range1.Find(7, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
Set lookup8 = range1.Find(8, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
Set lookup9 = range1.Find(9, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)

''''populate missing cells until one of each numbers from 1 to 9 is found''''

With Range("A1")
    Do Until Not lookup1 Is Nothing And Not lookup2 Is Nothing And Not lookup3 Is Nothing And Not lookup4 Is Nothing And Not lookup5 Is Nothing And Not lookup6 Is Nothing And Not lookup7 Is Nothing And Not lookup8 Is Nothing And Not lookup9 Is Nothing
    For i = 1 To emptycellcount
        .Offset(emptyrow(i), emptycol(i)).Value = Int((9 - 1 + 1) * Rnd + 1)
    Next i

    Set lookup1 = range1.Find(1, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    Set lookup2 = range1.Find(2, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    Set lookup3 = range1.Find(3, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    Set lookup4 = range1.Find(4, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    Set lookup5 = range1.Find(5, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    Set lookup6 = range1.Find(6, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    Set lookup7 = range1.Find(7, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    Set lookup8 = range1.Find(8, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    Set lookup9 = range1.Find(9, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)

    Loop
End With

End Sub
```

So I guess my questions are:

1. Am I on the right track? Is there a more efficient way of doing this using my line of logic?
2. Is there an entirely different, and better way to code this?

Thanks!

Comment: There is a nice little book "Programming Sudoku" by Wei-Meng Lee that discusses how to write a Sudoku solver in VB.Net. The code could be modified to VBA without great difficulty. The book is 10 years old, so it isn't exactly cutting edge, but it is a good place to start. At the very least, skimming it should give you some ideas.

Comment: If you finish implementing your code and make it work as intended, "making it more efficient" is exactly what [codereview.se] does.

Comment: Tip: when you feel the need for numbered variables, it's usually a sign that you need a data structure. Have you considered using an array?